# Visual Studio Code : Python Custom Interpreter - Autocomplete not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with a custom Python Interpreter. Unfortunately autocomplete doesnt seem to work on any of the packages stores in a custom site-packages path i have:

```
/home/yraaj/.cache/bazel/external/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

This path is in my PYTHONPATH in .bashrc, so running commands via the command line works. But VS Code doesn't know of this. How on earth do I tell VS Code about the above path? This is straightforward in Pycharm but i can't find any instructions on VS Code

Comment: check out this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: This isn't helpful at all. WHere do i even begin?

Comment: I added a `      "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/home/yraaj/.cache/bazel/_bazel_yraaj/8e69e8bf9bbcce5a3abd7fa64fb35ecc/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/atg/experimental/rnd/beenet/beenet_notebook.runfiles/pythonhome_pypi/lib/python3.7/site-packages"]` but that doesnt work

Comment: have you set the environment in vscode? You can try that first (following the link above) or set the pythonPath manually as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: huh isn't pythonpath referring to the python binary to use? what does that have to do with PYTHONPATH

Comment: If you're using the wrong python binary then it probably looking for libraries in the wrong place

Comment: Setting the location of your `site-packages` directory shouldn't be necessary as @NicolasMartinez pointed out. That should be picked up by Python itself which then it picked up by the Python extension (which I'm assuming you have installed). So that means making sure that `/home/yraaj/.cache/bazel/external/python3/bin/python` is set as your interpreter in the Python extension as linked to by Nicolas in his first comment.